# Add quote in javascript generated links

Tags: javascript

How do i fix this link in javascript.

```
<a href="javascript:clientGalleryLink(Business)">Link</a>
```

Its missing single quotes around 'Business'

Javascript:

```
html += "<option value='javascript:clientGalleryLink(" + titleArray[x] + ")'>" + titleArray[x] + "</option>";
```

Comment: your two snippets don't match. one is an `<a>` and the other is an `<option>`. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `\` to escape the quotes

```
html += "<option value='javascript:clientGalleryLink(\"" + titleArray[x] + "\")'>" + titleArray[x] + "</option>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href='javascript:clientGalleryLink("Business")'>Link</a>
html += "<option value='javascript:clientGalleryLink(\"" + titleArray[x] + "\")'>" + titleArray[x] + "</option>";
```

Could you please try this one out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add slashes:

```
\"" + titleArray[x] + "\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to escape the attribute quotes and thus giving you the single inner quotes like you show in your example.

```
html += "<option value=\"javascript:clientGalleryLink('" + titleArray[x] + "')\">" + titleArray[x] + "</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Escaping problems like this is why it's best to avoid creating JavaScript-in-HTML dynamically in strings. The `javascript:` pseudo-URL scheme should also never be used.

Instead, consider an ‘unobtrusive scripting’ approach: move the data out of an embedded JS string and into normal attributes, such as `class` or, if the link corresponds to a particular element on the page, the `href` itself:

```
<a class="gallerylink" href="#Business">Link</a>

for (var i= document.links.length; i-->0;) {
    if (document.links[i].className==='gallerylink') {
        document.links[i].onclick= function() {
            clientGalleryLink(this.hash.substring(1));
            return false;
        };
    }
}
```

The second example:

```
html += "<option value='javascript:clientGalleryLink(" + titleArray[x] + ")'>" + titleArray[x] + "</option>";
```

is just a mess. Aside from the lack of `\'` quoting around the titleArray value, and the lack of HTML-escaping or JS-string-literal-escaping on the titleArrays (so if you have `'"<&` characters in the title you've got problems).

Are you expecting the script to get executed when the option is chosen just because you've put it in the `value`? It won't.

Better to use the DOM objects than trying to mess around inserting JavaScript inside HTML inside JavaScript inside HTML. For example, if you're looking for a select box that calls `clientGalleryLink` every time the selected option is changed:

```
<div id="PlaceWhereYouWantToPutTheSelectBox"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var s= document.createElement('select');
    for (var i= 0; i<titleArray.length; i++) {
        s.options[i]= new Option(titleArray[i], titleArray[i]);
    }
    s.onchange= function() {
        clientGalleryLink(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
    };
    document.getElementById('PlaceWhereYouWantToPutTheSelectBox').appendChild(s);
</script>
```

No ugly escaping necessary, no cross-site-scripting security holes.